# How to avoid exitting the game and displaying part of the code?

Tags: java, while-loop, return-value

I've created a game and i wanted to improve it a bit by letting the player play it again, whether he lost or won. In the code below, the reutrn statement breaks the game (as it was initially intended to), but now I'd like the code to skip directly to asking the player about another game after the winning, and I'm stuck here. My goal is for the application not to display the "game over" statement after the game is won.

```
public static void gameStart() {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generatedRandomNumber = new Random();
        int randomNumber = generatedRandomNumber.nextInt(100 + 1); // +1 , because (100) bounds declares and int from 0
                                                                    // to 99 and that's what we want to avoid
        System.out.println("Hello!\nI've just generated a random number between 1 and 100, can you guess it? \n");
        String again = "y";
        while (again.equals("y")) {
            System.out.println("You have 5 attempts!");
            int j = 5;
            while (j > 0) {
                int userInput = scanner.nextInt();
                if (userInput > 100 || userInput < 1) {
                    System.out.println("C'mon, the range is 1 - 100, it's not that hard:)");
                    j = j + 1; // this is to keep the 5 chances up; we don't wanna count the out of bounds shot
                                // as a missed hit
                }
                if (userInput > randomNumber && userInput <= 100) { // this avoids the if loop run if the userInput
                                                                    // exceeds the limit
                    System.out.println("Try a lower number my friend!");
                } else if (userInput < randomNumber && userInput >= 1) {// this avoids the if loop run if the userInput
                                                                        // exceeds the limit
                    System.out.println("Try a higher number my friend!");
                } else if (userInput == randomNumber) {
                    System.out.println("You win! The mysterious number was " + randomNumber + "!!");
                    return;
                }
                j--;
            }
            System.out.println("\n\nGame over! The mysterious number was: " + randomNumber);
            System.out.println("\n\n Would you like to try again? (y/n)");
            again = scanner.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing this game, have a good day!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 System.out.println("\n\nGame over! The mysterious number was: " + randomNumber);
```

Put this line outside of the while-loop so it will be displayed in all cases.

Replace it with a message to the user that they guessed the right number.

You may want to consider adding a boolean variable that will track whether the user won or lost.

If the user guesses the right answer, set this boolean variable to indicate the they won.

Wrap the code that displays the "Game Over!" message with an if statement that check the value of that boolean variable so the message will only display if the user won.

Comment: yeah, that should work, now I just need to figure out how to put it all in code properly..still a beginner:) Thank you!

Comment: So this is how I managed to solve this problem:) Thanks very much for your help! https://github.com/putonsky/improved-potato

Comment: Great job! You got the loop control down pat! I don't see why you need to check that the user inputted a number within range more than once. `if (userInput > 100 || userInput < 1) {//out of range }` validates whether the input is in range. The next if-statements won't need to repeat the same action if you put them in the else part of the first if-statement that check range. `else if (userInput > randomNumber && userInput <= 100) { //"try lower} else if (userInput < randomNumber && userInput >= 1)`. Your code works, but you could improve it by making it more concise. Good Luck!